# Connect a react-native app with a vibration sensor using bluetooth

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect a vibration sensor to a react-native app using bluetooth.

I tryed to use Polidea solution for bluetooth
https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx

I basically started by copying their example here 
https://www.polidea.com/blog/ReactNative_and_Bluetooth_to_An_Other_level/

I have the error:

> Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null

I'd like to know

1. How to fix this?
2. Is `react-native-ble-plx` the best way to do what I want : getting data from a sensor every .4 seconds and displaying a chart showing the spectrum of vibration signal in my react native app

ble_test.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';
export default class Ble_test extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          this.manager.onStateChange((state) => {
            if (state === 'PoweredOn') this.scanAndConnect()
          })
        } else {
          this.scanAndConnect()
        }
      }

    constructor() {
      super()
      this.manager = new BleManager()
      this.state = {info: "", values: {}}
      this.prefixUUID = "f000aa"
      this.suffixUUID = "-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"
      this.sensors = {
        0: "Temperature",
        1: "Accelerometer",
        2: "Humidity",
        3: "Magnetometer",
        4: "Barometer",
        5: "Gyroscope"
      }
    }
    scanAndConnect() {
        this.manager.startDeviceScan(null,
                                     null, (error, device) => {
          this.info("Scanning...")
          console.log(device)

          if (error) {
            this.error(error.message)
            return
          }

          if (device.name === 'TI BLE Bose Mini II SoundLink' || device.name === 'Bose Mini II SoundLink') {
            this.info("Connecting to Bose")
            this.manager.stopDeviceScan()
            device.connect()
              .then((device) => {
                this.info("Discovering services and characteristics")
                return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
              })
              .then((device) => {
                this.info("Setting notifications")
                return this.setupNotifications(device)
              })
              .then(() => {
                this.info("Listening...")
              }, (error) => {
                this.error(error.message)
              })
          }
        });
      }



async setupNotifications(device) {
    for (const id in this.sensors) {
      const service = this.serviceUUID(id)
      const characteristicW = this.writeUUID(id)
      const characteristicN = this.notifyUUID(id)

      const characteristic = await device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(
        service, characteristicW, "AQ==" /* 0x01 in hex */
      )

      device.monitorCharacteristicForService(service, characteristicN, (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message)
          return
        }
        this.updateValue(characteristic.uuid, characteristic.value)
      })
    }
  }



    serviceUUID(num) {
      return this.prefixUUID + num + "0" + this.suffixUUID
    }

    notifyUUID(num) {
      return this.prefixUUID + num + "1" + this.suffixUUID
    }

    writeUUID(num) {
      return this.prefixUUID + num + "2" + this.suffixUUID
    }

    info(message) {
        this.setState({info: message})
    }

    error(message) {
        this.setState({info: "ERROR: " + message})
    }

    updateValue(key, value) { 
        this.setState({values: {...this.state.values, [key]: value}})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            <Text>{this.state.info}</Text>
            {Object.keys(this.sensors).map((key) => {
                return <Text key={key}>
                        {this.sensors[key] + ": " + (this.state.values[this.notifyUUID(key)] || "-")}
                        </Text>
            })}
            </View>
        )
        }
    }
```

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import Ble_test from "./Components/Ble_test";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true)
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
      <Ble_test/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code you used?

Comment: i added the code